# Java Palindrome program which does work with phrases

Tags: string, palindrome

I am trying to create a palindrome application in Java but my code doesn't work with phrase's especially when the phrase's begin with a capital letter.

Comment: Thank you ! It works for capital letters but it still doesn't recognise palindrome sentences.

Answer (score 0):

use **equalsIgnoreCase()** instead of equals().
equalsIgnoreCase compares the String to another String, ignoring case considerations.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem you could use tolowercase so that regardless of what the user input is you are testing both the provided phrase and reverse phrase in the same capitalization or lack there of. [Check this tutorial out for more details](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_tolowercase.htm)